# ArraryList attachment in the session

Tags: java, session, servlets

I have attached one array list into session from the `servlet` and after attaching ,I am clearing that `arraylist` in `servlet`, so it's getting clear from session also.

Could you please give the reason??

Comment: You are probably working with the same list object.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your question is not a very well shaped for Stack Overflow, I think I got what you mean.

So you have a

```
List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

in your code somewhere, you

1. put it in the session
2. and somewhere else you do a `.clear()` on it.

Right?

The problem is, that on the contrary to what you think, you have only **one** `ArrayList` instance. It is the same that is "in the" session and that is "in your servlet". Only that you have a different reference pointing to it...

What you need to do is attach a *different* instance of your list instance to your session:

```
//this creates a new list instance, with references to the same objects
List<MyClass> myNewList = new ArrayList<MyClass>(myList);
```

And "attach" this `myNewList` to the session. This way, the resulting two lists can be handled differently, they can have different content. If you alter one, the other will remain untouched.

I however advise to rethink your structure, shared information is always an issue to be dealt with carefully, [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://jcip.net/) is a key book to read when dealing with these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it will get clear from the session also because you are adding an reference to the array collection in the session. So both the array list objects, the one in the session and the one in your code ( after list has been added to the session ) refers to the same object in the memory. So if you clear the ArrayList object, then the underlying object contained in the session which also refers to the same object, gets clear.

To make your code working you can do one thing. Create a clone of your ArrayList and put that list into the session. Then do whatever you want to do with your object. It won't affect the object that is residing in the session.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously after setting the ArrayList in the session , you continue using the arraylist and you edit it.

But you should be aware that, What you have set in the session is just a memory reference to the actual arraylist.
Any change you make will still affect, as both variables point to the same list in memory.

To avoid you can

1) After you set the array list in session , assign a null to variable, so that you don't unknowingly continue to use it

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList ();

session.setAttribute("list",list);

list = null ; // Assigning the variable to null
```